# vuforia augmented reality with unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

[error image form visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7lPh.png)

i download Vuforia Core Samples

and download last version vurforia sdk

and i have Unity 2017.3.0b4 with vuforia

and i use visual studio enterprise 2017 to edit scripts

what the solution for these errors?

The type or namespace name 'ReconstructionBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'PropBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'SurfaceBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'ReconstructionBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'Prop' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'Surface' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[error image form visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7lPh.png)

Comment: Contact Vuforia. It looks to me like the Vuforia plugin isn't set up for Unity 2017 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Activate Vuforia in the XR Settings under Player Settings. [Refer Link](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity-2017-2-beta.html#add-targets).

```
Edited:

1. Be sure to install Vuforia AR Support from the Download Assistant or XR Settings
2. Activate Vuforia AR Support in XR Settings
3. Then import the samples
```